# dos2unix format conversion error while execution through TeamCity

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, teamcity, dos2unix

While trying to transfer file from Windows to Unix Azure environment, I am getting error dos2unix format error

*dos2unix -o /xyz/home/ABC_efg.txt failed to execute dos2unix format change.*

I tried to run a PS script to fix it but does seem to work .

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse *.txt | % { $x = get-content -raw -path $_.fullname; $x -replace "`r`n","`n" | set-content -NoNewline -path $_.fullname }
```

Comment: Thanks for assistance @Theo , i was able to resolve the issue using -replace as suggested by you.

Comment: Thanks for the nice feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `-replace`, I would prefer to read the content(s) as string array and join these strings with "`n".
Something like this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter '*.txt' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
$files | ForEach-Object { 
    (Get-Content -Path $_) -join "`n" | Set-Content -Path $_ -NoNewline -WhatIf
}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch if you are satisfied with the outout shown in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Well, part of the issue is that you are piping a string to `Set-Content` and then trying to use that string to determine where to save the file. Try changing the last part from:

```
$x -replace "`r`n","`n" | set-content -NoNewline -path $_.fullname
```

to this:

```
set-content -NoNewline -path $_.fullname -value ($x -replace "`r`n","`n")
```

If that doesn't update the formatting like you expect it to you may need to use the `-Encoding` parameter for `Set-Content`. I'm not real familiar with encoding though, so I am not sure about that.

Comment: I tried replacing the last part but the output behavior is not as per expectation . Will try to explore Encoding as i am also not familiar with it. Thanks for your suggestions @TheMadTechnician